# Private repo dependency installs but "Cannot Find Module"

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have a project that requires a private repo as a dependency. So, projectA has this included in the package.json as `"projectB": "user/repo"`. This installs just fine, and is listed in projectA node_modules. The problem is, that node throws and error where I require the functions of the dependency. The error being that `"Cannot find module projectB"`. As mentioned, projectB is listed in node_modules. Here is the structure of projectB:

```
.
├── README.md
├── file1.js
├── file2.js
├── file3.js
├── file4.js
└── package.json
```

It also has its own node_modules, but I've left that out. Now, here is what file1.js might look like:

```
function getResult (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

module.exports = { getResult }
```

And here is what projectA looks like:

```
var calculate = require('projectB').file1.getResult; // I've tried this in several other ways too
```

Calling calculate results in the `"Cannot find module error"`. Have I done something fundamentally wrong in setting up for using a private repo as dependency and/or requiring it wrong?

**Update projectB package.json**

```
{
  "name": "projectB",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Backend utility functions",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/user/repo.git"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com//user/repo/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com//user/repo#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.25",
    "redis": "^2.7.1",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the `package.json` for `projectB` look like? It needs to declare a `main` unless it has `index.js`

Comment: updated post, if this is just a bunch of helper functions, what would a main.js look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`projectB` needs to be updated to set an appropriate [`main`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main), but by default this will be `index.js`. You could do something like the following:

```
// projectB/index.js
exports.file1 = require("./file1");
exports.file2 = require("./file2");
exports.file3 = require("./file3");
exports.file4 = require("./file4");
```

It's actually a pretty common pattern to have an `index.js` that does nothing but export from library files.

Comment: Thanks. The funny thing is, I started off that way, and then removed it thinking it was a needless step. Apparently not!